# SQL Server export wizard is changing all the data to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, import, wizard

I am trying to export data from SQL Server to Excel and then upload that data into another SQL Server instance.

While the export looks like it's working - no errors or warnings - I get an Excel file where all the data is "general" format.

When uploading the Excel to the new server, all columns are of type `nvarchar`, no dates floats int etc.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Excel is the wrong tool for the job. If you want to transfer data between SQL servers without using Database Backups or Linked Servers then take a look at the [BCP Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) which can transfer data preserving native types.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this